# How can I pass an enum value to the OnClick method of a button?

Tags: unity, c#

I am making a UI system for my game where I want to use an `enum` to define different UI modes. But `OnClick` function on button doesn't show method which receive `enum`s.

I heard I can pass an integer value to `OnClick` method and then somehow transform it into an enum. What can I do about it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is no compatible callback for SwitchUIMode(UIModes uiModes) In the standard click events for a button. You need to extend your own UnityEvent with that type.

Comment: Also consider using a stack to keep track of your menu and simply push/pop instantiated game objects containing your menu layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have integer as parameter to your click function and then cast it to the enum directly:

```
public void SwitchUIMode(int uiMode)
{
   UIModes currentMode = (UIModes)uiMode;
   switch (currentMode)
   {
       case UIModes.MainMenu:
       ...
   }
}
```